# Should you say RIP when you know someone commits suicide?

Tags: word-choice

I've been told that "RIP" is not suitable in this case.

Is that true or there is a better saying?

Comment: You do not seem to be asking for an explanation of RIP's meaning or correct grammar. You seem to be asking a question about etiquette or even religion.

Comment: You shouldn't say "RIP" or "rest in peace" because it is a cliché.

Comment: I believe RIP or its expanded form is very formal and used only in situations like announcements, tombstones and so on. If you had known the person, you are expected to take the trouble of saying something a bit more sensitive. How the person died may not be relevant as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I just want to make sure the phrase is used in the right way in case it is used.

Comment: Something being a cliche is not, in itself, a reason not to use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

RIP is Latin for *requiescat in pace,* which means *may he rest in peace.* With that said, you're asking whether a person should rest in peace after committing suicide, which is a rather philosophical question. So in the end, it gets down to this:

If you respect a person after they had committed suicide and you wish they rest in peace, then using "RIP" for whatever purpose is suitable.

If for whatever reason (for example religious reason) you don't think a certain person should rest in peace, then you won't use "RIP".